# js Google Visualisazion API license

Tags: google-visualization, google-api-js-client

> Is the Google javascript API open source, and if so, where can I find it?

I'm using the visualization library to display some data, but there are issues regarding the representation of the charts in different locales.

I found the issue tracker on googles github repo (https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues). A lot of issues seem to be left behind and my issue in particular dates back to may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Visualization API is not open source.  It is provided as a free service, but the source files must be referenced from their servers, and you are not permitted to reverse engineer them.  There are terms and conditions listed somewhere on developers.google.com/charts